# One-liner to quote string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Consider the following bash function:

```
function quote { 
    declare quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}
    echo "'$quoted'"
}
```

This function wraps the argument in single quotes, and replaces each existing single quote with the string `'\''`:

```
$ quote "a'b"
'a'\''b'
```

It seems like the function body could be written in one line:

```
function my_quote {
    echo "'${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"
}
```

However, this doesn't work for some reason:

```
$ my_quote "a'b"
'a\'\\'\'b'
```

So, my questions are (1) Why doesn't the one-line version work?, and (2) Is there some way to make it work by, say, adding some more backslashes?

By the way, if you're curious, this snippet demonstrates why such a function is useful:

```
foo="some string generated at runtime, possibly containing special characters"
cmd="somecommand $(quote "$foo")"
ssh user@host "$cmd"
```

Comment: See the `%q` specifier to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) It's probably how bash differently handles the parameter expansion inside `""` than the one in assignments. I see it actually as a bug since the quoted string is not properly unquoted. It works properly somehow if you use other variables inside i.e.

```
"${var//x/$other}"
```

(2) This is not a one-line way, just another way. You could place the variables on other places but it's still not one line in my opinion.

```
function my_quote {
    local r="'\''"
    echo "'${1//\'/$r}'"
}
```

You could also place an `echo` under a subshell `$()` but that's still two lines or two commands in one.

Comment: My gut feeling is that \ is processed once inside of `"` so each \\ becomes \. But a quick check showed that duplicating the \ doesn't work, either.

Comment: I noticed the local variable solution, but as you say it's not a one-liner.  The echo subshell is pretty clever, but I'm wondering if there's a fix that just involves proper quoting/escaping.